# When I need to pass data in between fragments or observe liveData in each fragment?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have data that I am fetching at the beginning of the application
and then I need to use that settingsLiveData through whole application.
I am thinking about 2 solutions
1.Create SettingsViewModel  and I can have instance of this viewModel in each fragment and observe there ( settingsLiveData can be modified only once ,when I fetch data)
2.  I just can observe once at the beginning of the application and then pass data in between fragments as argument?

If I go with first approach I can inject it in each Fragment and observe it even through it would be fetched and modified only once
or I can pass in between fragments the settings data as argument

````
class SettingsViewModel  @Inject constructor()  : ViewModel(){
  private val settingsMutableData = MutableLiveData<Settings>()
  private val errorMessageMutableData = MutableLiveData<String>()

  init {
    fetchSettings()
  }
  val settingsData: LiveData<Settings>
    get() = settingsMutableData

  val errorMessageData: LiveData<String>
    get() = errorMessageMutableData

  private fun fetchSettings() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      when (val result = fetchSettings()) {
        is Response.Success<Settings> -> {
          //tODO; miguche menak success stugel
          configMutableData.postValue(result.data)
        }
        is Response.Failure -> errorMessageMutableData.postValue(result.message)
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: `LiveData` are meant to be data holder with **lifecycle-awareness** of View state. If you share ViewModel across activities/ take it at application level as singleton, it can't sustain lifecycle of your View and cause memory leaks in certain state. I would suggest creating Repository and get your data from shared pref through it and provide it to your livedata from viewmodel attached to certain view (Activity/Fragment).

Comment: im also not entirely sure if `LiveData` can be observed by several different things

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede this SettingsData contains a lot of data ,it is huge data inside and I can't keep it in sharedPreferences

Comment: @a_local_nobody I don't get what do you mean?

Comment: can several things observe onto the same  LiveData object ?

Comment: No , but I have ViewModel not a liveData

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede but if I have ViewModel with activity scope in that case should I pass data in between fragments or observe it in each fragment ?

Comment: Then, try any other resource to hold your data like local sqlite db or simple files I/O. But sharing like your way has pitfalls and I would not recommend you to do that.

Comment: If you have ViewModel at activity scope (or shared between Fragments) then it's good approach.

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede Ok I see, but in that case if it is Activity scope which is better to observe that activity scope viewModel's liveData in each Fragment or I can just observe at the beginning and then just pass in between Fragments as bundle?

Comment: It'll be easy to observe `LiveData` in fragments which is scoped from activity rather than passing by arguments.

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede How it is easy? what makes observing easy compared with bundle?